# Why return statement doesn't stop the program?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I have a function that checks wether the user is viewing their profile or not. and here is my function.

```
func isUserViewCurrentUser() -> Bool {
    guard let user = userDataDelegate?.userData() else {
        return false
    }

    if user == Current.user {
        print("returning false: USER IS CURRENT USER")
        return false
    } else {
        print("returning true: USER IS NOT CURRENT USER")
        return true
    }

 }
```

Then I only run my function in the view will appear, the code supposed to stop after I print something:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    if isUserViewCurrentUser() == true {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        return
    } else {
        return
    }

    if let userID = userDataDelegate?.userData().userID {
        retrieveFollowerNumbers(userIdentifier: userID)
        return
    }

 }
```

But my console printed "returning true: USER IS NOT CURRENT USER" for a thousand times and never stop. I've looked everywhere in my code that I never run `isUserViewCurrentUser()` in a for loop or any loop.

This is my userData:

```
protocol SendUserDataDelegate {

    func userData() -> User
}
```

didSelect TableViewCell:

```
if let user = filteredUsers?[indexPath.row] {
        userToPass = user
        profileController?.userDataDelegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileController!, animated: true)

    }
```

And this code at my cellRowAtIndexPath:

```
if isUserViewCurrentUser() == true {
            cell.bioAndFollowStackView.addSubview(cell.followButtonOutlet)
        } else {
            if cell.followButtonOutlet != nil {
                cell.followButtonOutlet.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
```

sending user object when user tabs a tableview cell into another viewController. and I call it whenever I want to get a reference to the user object

Comment: Could you make a breakpoint and show the stacktrace on 2-3 time?

Comment: Use the debugger and see why this is happening.

Comment: You can use Breakpoint and check the call stack trace, logs your self the call stack (`NSThread. callStackSymbols()`), and also with XCode, check where is called `isUserViewCurrentUser()`.

Comment: yes, it appears that after the function gets executed in the viewWillAppear, it went to the function again then viewWillAppear, back to the function again. Never Stops although I put a return statement there.

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev yea when I print(Thread.callStackSymbols) I got a lot of number that I don't understand

Comment: I meant, that to understand why is it hapenning, it would be good to make a breakpoint within the 'problem' function and go over the breakpoin 2-3 times (no more, to not make it a huge repeated list). Then you can open 'Breakpoint' perspective in the Xcode (actually it opens automatically when you work with breakpoints) on the left side of Xcode (it replaces the project navigator). Here you can go through the calls - just click on a line and it opens corresponding function in your code. If it is still not clear. you could provide us with screen-shot or copy-paste the stack here.

Comment: Could be an infinite recursion loop.  is `Current` a class? can you post parts it's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personaly I see that you have 2 objects with different references and you check if they are equal ... even if the data inside is the same the actual references are not.

If that is the case, you can check them by something unique like id.

if user.id == Current.user.id { 
}

I don't know what you trying to achieve, but in my personal opinion (no offense) there is something smelly ... :). You can think for better solution.

Hope this will help, wish you all the best.

Comment: It might be an `Equatable` conforming object. And, in any case, the answer is not pertinent to the question.

Comment: I was just checking if the current user is previewing their own profile or not, and even if my code is bad, it should stop because I put a return statement

Answer (score 0):

In `viewWillAppear` you call `isUserViewCurrentUser()`, which calls `userDataDelegate.userData()`. You didn't post what `userData()` does, but I'll bet it either causes your view to appear again, or calls `isUserViewCurrentUser()` again.

In any case, please post `userData()` code...

Comment: so I just added userData, basically its a protocol function to transfer the user object from one controller into another controller

Comment: @BukaCakrawala You posted the protocol, please post the implementation of `userData()`

Comment: just did I just posted the code implementation from push segue to cellRowAtIndex

Comment: Your code is too hard for me to understand given the parts of it that you chose to post. Question. Does the problem still persist, if you move all of the code from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear` ?